# How to run one-off job?

Tags: kubernetes

I've found 2 different ways to run a one-off command in my kubernetes cluster:

### Method 1

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes/migrate.job.yaml
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=600s job/migrate-job
kubectl delete job/migrate-job
```

The problem with this is (a) it doesn't show me the output which I like to see, and (b) it's 3 commands

### Method 2

```
kubectl run migrate --stdin --tty --rm --restart=Never --image=example.org/app/php:v-$(VERSION) --command -- ./artisan -vvv migrate
```

This almost works except I also need a volume mount to run this command, which AFAIK would require a rather lengthy `--overrides` arg. If I could pull the override in from a file instead it'd probably work well. Can I do that?

I also need to to return the exit code if the command fails.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open ticket for this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/63214

A short term solution is to run your job like this:

```
kubectl run migrate --stdin --tty --rm --restart=Never --image=example.org/app/php:v-$(VERSION) --overrides="$(cat kubernetes/migrate.pod.yaml | y2j)"
```

Using [y2j](https://github.com/wildducktheories/y2j) to convert YAML to JSON so that I can use a standard pod manifest.

`migrate.pod.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: migrate-pod
spec:
    volumes:
        -   name: migrate-secrets-volume
            secret:
                secretName: google-service-account
    containers:
        -   name: migrate-container
            image: example.org/app/php
            command: ["./artisan",  "-vvv", "migrate"]
            stdin: true
            stdinOnce: true
            tty: true
            envFrom:
                -   secretRef:
                        name: dev-env
            volumeMounts:
                -   name: migrate-secrets-volume
                    mountPath: /app/secrets
                    readOnly: true
    restartPolicy: Never
    imagePullSecrets:
        -   name: regcred
```

Comment: Turns out `--image` is completely ignored if you use `--overrides` and it can't be omitted from the --override either, otherwise the container is malformed :\